# Vue testing a component that uses composables

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vitest

I'm using vitest to put together unit tests for components in my web app. I've run into an issue where my component uses a composable to get some state variables, and the composable is undefined when I run the test. Here is how the component uses the company composable:

```
const coreValueOptions = company()?.core_values.map((value: any) =>
  value.label.replace(/#/gi, ""),
);
```

I've tried mocking the composable here in the test, and this doesn't quite work, it only makes it so if I call the composable directly it returns 100, but if the composable is called through the CoreModalFilters component, it doesn't work.

```
import { describe, test, expect } from "vitest";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import CoreModalFilters from "../../components/core/modal/CoreModalFilters.vue";
import { company } from "../../composables/store";

const mock = vi.hoisted(() => {
    return {
      company: vi.fn(),
    };
  });

  vi.mock("../../composables/store", () => ({
    company: mock.company,
  }));
  vi.mocked(company).mockReturnValue(100);

describe("CoreModalFilters and all variants render correctly", async () => {

  test("correctly renders CoreModalFilter with default props", async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(CoreModalFilters, {
      propsData: {
        showModal: true,
      },
    });
    // const html = wrapper.html();
  });
});
```

and here are the composables

```
export const company = () => {
  return useStore().company;
};
```

error stack

```
 FAIL  tests/components/CoreModalFilters.test.js > CoreModalFilters and all variants render correctly > correctly renders CoreModalFilter with default props
ReferenceError: company is not defined
 ❯ setup components/core/modal/CoreModalFilters.vue:49:26
     47|   : ["Office Location", "Team", "Core Value"];
     48| 
     49| const coreValueOptions = company()?.core_values.map((value: any) =>
       |                          ^
     50|   value.label.replace(/#/gi, ""),
     51| );
 ❯ callWithErrorHandling node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:156:18
 ❯ setupStatefulComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7190:25
 ❯ setupComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7151:36
 ❯ mountComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5555:7
 ❯ processComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5521:9
 ❯ patch node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5007:11
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5664:11
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.run node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.cjs.js:182:19
 ❯ instance.update node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5770:51
```

Comment: What is the error message? It depends on how vitest works, but if it doesn't differ from jest in this regard, you can't mock a module inside describe(). Is there a reason why  vi.hoisted and vi.mock  aren't at top level?

Comment: The error is ReferenceError: company is not defined

I put the mock in the describe because I've just been trying things out. I'll move it back out to global scope.

Comment: @EstusFlask I've updated the test to follow that style, i still have the same issue, in jest I would do something like a .when() I think

Comment: vi.mocked can be inside a test if it's test-specific. You can also try to replace company import with mock.company in test file to access the spy to avoid possible reference problems caused by the way vitest deals with modules Please, add full error with call stack. It's unclear where the error occurs

Comment: I added the full error stack, sorry about that

Comment: Does the error not happen if you remove the mock? Can you provide the whole CoreModalFilters, or at least the parts with code that surrounds coreValueOptions and the imports?

Comment: yes, the error happens the same regardless of the mock.

Comment: Make sure CoreModalFilters has import { company }, this would prevent it from working normally but this would be a reasonable explanation. Then the problem is with the setup, this needs a reproduction

Comment: That gave me a new error, I think this is progress, I am going to try to make changes to my vitest config and go from there. I'll come back if I find anything